# \relax undefined in tocloft \cftchapaftersnum

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, tocloft

I found this error while try to compile latex document in my new machine:

```
! LaTeX Error: \relax undefined.
l.35 \renewcommand
            {\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
```

It didn't appear in my previous machine. I've just installed Miktex 2.9 there with basic standard
This is my very minimum working example. Hope it is clear enough. :

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftaftertoctitle}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapfont}{}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappagefont}{\itshape}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappagefont}{}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}}
.
.

\begin{document}
.
.
\end{document}
```

At first, looks like just forget to install one single package. But, after quick googling by `\relax undefined` keyword, I've learned that it is not as simple as I was thinking. Is it really those complicated, or indeed just one single package missing?

Comment: `\setlength` takes two arguments: the first is the length macro you want to assign a value to, the second is the length value in question. The second argument argument is missing in your code; you need to specify it.

Comment: There is only one line containing `\setlength` there, and all its arguments are complete. `\cftchapaftersnum` is modified by `\renewcommand`, not `\setlength`.

Comment: Not true. In your code, because you don't specify a length value for `\setlength`, the latter takes as its second argument the `\renewcommand` on the following line, hence the error you're getting; `\cftchapaftersnum` has nothing to do with it. See [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths#Length_manipulation) for more details on `\setlength`'s syntax.

Comment: Oh, okay. I've just notice my foolishness.

Comment: @Jubobs `\cftaftertoctitle` is not a length.

Comment: @egreg What jumped at me was `\setlength` missing its second argument, but I didn't investigate further...

Comment: @Jubobs I too thought it was a length, at first, but in this case the error would have been different: `! Missing number, treated as zero.`

Comment: @egreg `:)` Your brain must be Turing complete, because mine can't predict the error one should get in a particular situation. Not yet, anyway.

Comment: @Jubobs The trick is trying it out. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you get is indeed puzzling: forgetting the second argument for `\setlength` most of the times results in

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
```

or, if a number happens to follow, in

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

Let's see why you get the mysterious

```
! LaTeX Error: \relax undefined.
```

error message.

First of all, as already observed in the comments, you're forgetting the second argument to `\setlength`, but TeX doesn't know it and takes as argument the following token or braced group. In this case it finds `\renewcommand`, so what you get is

```
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitle}\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
```

(the space coming from the end-of-line is ignored because TeX is looking for a normal argument).

Now TeX expands `\setlength` using its definition:

```
% latex.ltx, line 1874:
\def\setlength#1#2{#1#2\relax}
```

so you get

```
\cftaftertoctitle\renewcommand\relax{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
```

Now, `\cftaftertoctitle` is *NOT* a parameter, but a macro which by default expands to nothing. Hence TeX is confronted with

```
\renewcommand\relax{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
```

which is illegal, because *any* command equivalent to `\relax` is undefined as far as LaTeX is concerned.

In conclusion, your code is flawed in two ways:

1. You're missing an argument for `\setlength`;
2. You're trying to set a macro to a length, which is illegal.

Indeed, also `\setlength{\cftaftertoctitle}{2pt}` would raise another puzzling error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \setlength{\cftaftertoctitle}{2pt}
```

Exercise: find out why.